# separating the output of tags

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to seperate each output individually. Is there any possible way to do this ?

```
<?php echo stripslashes($row['meta_keys'] = str_replace(',',' ',$row['meta_keys'])) ?>
```

I want to link each one to a specific thing, but it all comes out as 1 a link

I did `<a href=""><?php echo stripslashes($row['meta_keys'] = str_replace(',',' ',$row['meta_keys'])) ?></a>` but again, it all came out as one link. Any simple way to do this?

Comment: @Barmar I basically have my meta tags like this,that,no,go,so I want each of them linking to something entirely diff. But when I go to wrap the <a> around that string, it link all at once. Any ideas?

Comment: Explode it into an array, and then use a `foreach` loop. Isn't that obvious? But it would be better not to put a comma-separated list into the database in the first place. Use a table with a separate row for each tag.